# How to Solve "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where clause'"

Tags: php, laravel

**The screenshot of the error I got is given below.**

[image: Error Message]

**The LoginController code which is used in the login is given below**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Hash;
use App\Models\Customer;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function login(){
        return view('user.login');
    }
    public function check(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials= $request->validate([
            'username' => ['required'],
            'password' => ['required'],
        ]);
        if(Auth::attempt([$credentials])){
            return view('welcome');
        }
        else{
            return view('unauth');
        }
    }
}
```

**The Customer.php Model is given below**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable=[
        'name',
        'username',
        'password',
        'email',
        'invoice',
        'kwh',
        'warranty',
        'date'
    ];
}
```

**The code in web.php is given below**

```
Route::get('/login', [LoginController::class,'login']);
Route::post('/check',[LoginController::class,'check'])->name('check');
Route::get('/unauthorizedaccess', function () {
    return view('unauth');
});
```

**The Login.blade.php code is given below**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="{{asset('css/customs.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" >
    <title>Login Form</title>
  </head>
  <body style=" background-image: url({{url('img/img-1.webp')}});">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <form action="{{ route('check') }}" method="POST" class="mx-auto formlogin">
              {!! csrf_field() !!}
                <div style="text-align: center;">
                    <img src="{{url('img/logo.webp')}}" alt="logo" width="170px;">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3 mt-5">
                  <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Enter your Username</label>
                  <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                  <label for="Password" class="form-label">Enter your Password</label>
                  <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required>
                  <a style="text-decoration: none;" href=""><div id="emailHelp" style="color: #0d6efd;" class="form-text mt-3">Forget password ?</div></a>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-5">Login</button>
                <div id="emailHelp" style="color:black; font-weight:600; text-align:center;" class="form-text mt-3 cus_mobile_issues">Don't Have an Account? <a style="text-decoration:none;" href="">Click Here</a></div>
              </form>
        </div>
    <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

These are the files which are related to the login. I'm not an expert on laravel, How can I solve this. Thank you in advance

Comment: $credentials already return array so no need to wrap them again array in Auth
::attempt.  if(Auth::attempt($credentials)){

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Laravel`, The `Auth::attempt` method will try to fetch column name from the **Keys** of **Associative Array** / **Array of key - value pairs**, But when you pass an **Array**, Since it only has `index`, It will get the index instead of key which supposed to be a column name. This is why the column name becomes `0` and the error popsup.

As **@John Lobo** mentioned, the `$request->validate` already returning an **Associative Array**, But you are converting it to an **Array** by wrapping it `Auth::attempt([$credentials])`.

you can simply pass `$credentials` without wrapping it to solve this issue.

```php
if(Auth::attempt($credentials)){
    return view('welcome');
}
```